# Assign textbox using model with variable values

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 4 textbox in the view and I need to assign values i get from the database in a variable all together because of my table struture. Now i'm facing problem to assign values to the controls in view and update the same database using the same controls.Please help,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // SettingsModel smodel = new SettingsModel();
    // tblSettings tableset = new tblSettings();

    var dat = _Settings.GetSettings().ToDictionary(s => s.Desc, s => s.Settings, StringComparer.Ordinal);
    return View();
}
```

> //dat i get all the values from tablestructure.I couldnt figureouthow
>   to apply these values to textboxes i have in the view using model. as
>   i need to update the same table using the textbox

table structure:
ID(int), Settings(nvarchar) ,Desc (nvarchar)

[image]

UPDATE:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
   .Name("startpicker")
   .Interval(60)
 //.Value("10:00 AM")
   )
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
   .Name("endpicker")
   .Interval(60)
 //.Value("10:00 AM")
   )
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.DefaultState, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width: 118px;", id = "statetxt" }) </td>
```

Thankyou for replying. I get all values assigned except for tooltipcheckbox and kendo timepicker:

HEre is my code in controller:

> ```
>   settingsmodel smodel=new settingsmodel();
>       if (dat.ContainsKey("Tooltips"))
>       smodel.tooltip =Convert.ToBoolean(dat["Tooltips"]);
> ```
>
> //i get the value 0 in Tooltips
>   //it throws error as string was not recognized as a valid boolean

settingsmodel:

```
 public bool tooltip { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where are you passing the data from the controller to the view? Please post your view code also.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your model into the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // SettingsModel smodel = new SettingsModel();
    // tblSettings tableset = new tblSettings();

    var dat = _Settings.GetSettings().ToDictionary(s => s.Desc, s => s.Settings, StringComparer.Ordinal);
    return View(dat); //dat is your model.
}
```

And inside the view you can get the data from model.

Your model seems like a dictionary do your view side would be similar to the followings..

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in ((IDictionary<string, string>) Model))
{
    <input type="text">@item.Value</input>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please pass your model to the view.

change this:

```
return View();
```

to

```
return View(dat);
```

hope this works

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as follows:

1. Pass your model to view

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var model = //your model
       return View(models); 
   }
   ```
2. Create `Strongly type View`

   ```
   @model YourModelTypeName

   @using (Html.BeginForm("TestHtmlRedirect", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
   {
       // Your Controls
       // for Eg:
       // @Html.textboxfor(m => Model.Setting); // will create text box for setting property   
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   }
   ```
3. Capture the model in post action as follows:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(ModelType model)
   {
       // on submitting your text box values entered by ysers will get bind in model
       // Your model will contain all values entered by user 
   }
   ```